# Connection could not be established with host smtp.googlemail.com

Tags: swift, laravel, smtp

I have an error

> Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host
>   smtp.googlemail.com [Unable to find the socket transport "tsl" - did
>   you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? #1]

How can I handle it?
Please help me

Comment: what is in your .env file

Answer (score 1):

use like this in your `.env` file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your_mail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=your_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```